# Swift 4.2 Search contacts with Search Bar using Contacts Framework

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, contacts

I'm currently working on a Contact app just to test some features and I'm stuck with the search bar. I can't search between all my contacts in the homepage. Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10

```
class ContactsViewController: UITableViewController, CNContactViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
// Outlet for Search Bar
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

this is the definition of my Delegate on IBOutlet

then my func to show contacts in the homepage

```
/ * Show Contacts *
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if contactList != nil {
        return contactList.count
    }
    return 0
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath)

    let contact: CNContact!
    contact = contactList[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let contact = contactList[indexPath.row]
    let controller = CNContactViewController(for: contact)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

How can I do this searchBar look through my contacts using as key Name or Surname.

Here is one of my attempt but I get an error with `contains`:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false

        view.endEditing(true)

        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true

        filteredData = contactList.filter({$0.contains(searchBar.text!)})

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - your table view data source and delegate methods are all based on `contactList` but when searching you are updated `filteredData`. Your data source and delegate methods need to based their results on `filteredData` while performing a search.

Comment: So I should change all contactList references with filteredData?

Comment: While searching, yes.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't get when should I use filteredData and when to use contactList

Comment: You use filteredData when searching and contactList when not.

Comment: @rmaddy can't solve. I can't get it when to replace, cause when I put the data into contactList, filteredData will always be empty so I will get index out of bounds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `contactList` array contains `CNContact` instances. So the `$0` in your `filter` is a `CNContact`. `contains` fails because `CNContact` has no `contains` method.

Think about what you would need to write if you had a single `CNContact` variable and you want to see if the contact's name contained the search text.

And you probably don't want `contains` because you probably want to do a case-insensitive, diacritic-insentsitve search.

Here's an example by looking at the contact's given and family name properties. Add other properties as needed:

```
filteredData = contactList.filter {
    $0.givenName.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil ||
    $0.familyName.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil
}
```

Comment: I was trying something like that already but got: Cannot assign value of type '[CNContact]' to type '[String]'

Comment: Sounds like you mistakenly declared `filteredData` as `[String]` instead of `[CNContact]`. `filteredData` should have the same type as `contactList`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, now I got stuck on Index out of range on this if: if inSearchMode {
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            contact = contactList[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
        }

Comment: basically my error is I can't save into text cause can't convert CNContact to String

Comment: You need to see my comment below your question.